# aws ingress controller to expose service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, ingress-controller

I'm using [kubernetes-sigs.github.io](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/examples/echo_server/) as a reference to expose my app on eks using one load balancer. I got their example working with just a slight modification in the annotation. I added the `group.name`.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: echoserver
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echoserver
  namespace: echoserver
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echoserver
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echoserver
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: k8s.gcr.io/e2e-test-images/echoserver:2.5
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: echoserver
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echoserver
  namespace: echoserver
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: echoserver
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: echoserver
  namespace: echoserver
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: subnet-1,subnet-2,subnet-3
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: Environment=dev,Team=test
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: test.apps
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /echoserver
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: echoserver
                port:
                  number: 80
```

I am able to curl the ext ip of the ingress with a `/echoserver` and see the expected output. However, I couldn't get it to work for my app. I tried using another popular test image, game-2048, but it also didn't work. I just need 404 Not Found when I try to curl or visit in browser. What am I missing?

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: game-2048
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: game-2048
  name: deployment-2048
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: app-2048
  replicas: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: app-2048
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: alexwhen/docker-2048
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: app-2048
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: game-2048
  name: service-2048
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: app-2048
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: game-2048
  name: ingress-2048
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: subnet-1,subnet-2,subnet-3
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: Environment=dev,Team=test
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: test.apps
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /game
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service-2048
                port:
                  number: 80
```